# Ecobee3 lite connected to Lennox Pulse G14Q Heat/Air Condition

Tags: thermostat, lennox, wifi

I have read a similar wifi thermo connection feed here and they had success hooking the C wire to the T terminal on the furnace. 
I can get power to run the thermo from the T terminal, but when I do, the furnace blower kicks in immediately upon thermostat demand and BLOWER runs at high speed. It shouldn't kick on until the furnace fan (air for the combustion) runs for 30 seconds and then the ignitor spark plug kicks in and warms the furnace BEFORE the Blower kicks in and circulates the heated air.
I wired the thermo with the blue wire to the T terminal on the furnace and also tried the PEK interface setup and there was no change to the Blower kicking in on high.

Any suggestions and ideas would be very helpful. Ive resorted to putting the old thermo in and everything works fine (4 wire system)

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both ends?

Answer (score 0):

Check to insure the blower control selection in the initial set up is set to ‘controlled by HVAC’ and not ecobee. The default is set to ecobee.